# How to transmit data through human body?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields

I'm doing a bit of research on data transfer via human body(skin).I read that  low-frequency electromagnetic waves can be transmitted through the skin.
What frequency and how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best comparision I can think is the low frequency waves that are used in communicating with submerged submarines, and skin is mostly water, but the information rate transmission rate will be terribly slow. VLF radio waves (3–30 kHz) can penetrate seawater to a depth of approximately 20 meters. Hence a submarine at shallow depth can use these frequencies.

Sound travels far in water, and underwater loudspeakers and hydrophones can cover quite a gap. Apparently, both the American (SOSUS) and the Russian Navy have placed sonic communication equipment in the seabed of areas frequently traveled by their submarines and connected it by underwater communications cables to their land stations.

My point is that VLF use is  possible, but with slow data transmision rates, compared to sound, as used in ultrasound scanners, which gives a better performance.

Comment: So if I can make a vlf transmitter and receiver would it transmit through the skin.or as the distance is slow it would just be wireless right?

Comment: If VLF is good for 20 metres of water, it should be OK for, hopefully :) not more 1/2 metre of tissue.